# Receiving signal SIGSEGV segmentation fault

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am at the end of my nerves, with this Code.
When I try to run it, it crashes and if I try to debug, it gets :
program received signal SIGSEGV segmentation fault.

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with it ((

Here is the Code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>#include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #define ROWS 11 //Zeilen
    #define COLS 11 //Spalten
    #define MAUSX 5
    #define MAUSY 5
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    char l=0;


    char arr[ROWS][COLS] =
        {
        {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
        {'*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*'},
        {'*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ','*'},
        {'*',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
        {'*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ','*'},
        {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ','o','*',' ','*','*','*'},
        {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','A'},
        {'*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
        {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
        {'A',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
        {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
        };


    void ifo(int x,int y){


    if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x-1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y-1][x]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    if(arr[y][x-1]==' ' && arr[y-1][x]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    if(arr[y][x-1]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    if(arr[y-1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
    }




    int suche(int x, int y){


    ifo(x, y);


    if(l%2){
    if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
    if(arr[y][x+1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
    if(arr[y][x-1]==' ') {x--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y+1][x]==' ') {y++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y][x+1]==' ') {x++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y-1][x]==' ') {y--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    }
    else{
    if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe();}
    if(arr[y][x+1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
    if(arr[y-1][x]==' ') {y--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y][x+1]==' ') {x++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y+1][x]==' ') {y++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    if(arr[y][x-1]==' ') {x--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
    }


    while(1){


    if(y==a && x==b){ l++; break;}
    if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
    if(arr[y][x+1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
    if(arr[y-1][x]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; y--; }
    if(arr[y][x+1]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; x++; }
    if(arr[y+1][x]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; y++; }
    if(arr[y][x-1]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; x--; }


    }
    suche(x,y);
    }




    void ausgabe(){


        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){


        for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){


        printf("%c ", arr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        }
        exit(0);


    }


        int  main (){




    suche(9,7);




        return 0;}
```

To explain what is even happening :

I got an charackter array of [11] [11] elements, with an 'O' at the spot 5,5 . 
The code checks all directions, and if it is an space it moves to that cordinate and marks it also with an 'O'.

```
else{if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe();}
if(arr[y][x+1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
if(arr[y-1][x]==' ') {y--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
if(arr[y][x+1]==' ') {x++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
if(arr[y+1][x]==' ') {y++; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);}
if(arr[y][x-1]==' ') {x--; arr[y][x]='o'; suche(x,y);} }
```

When it gets to a point, where he cant move to another direction, because he is stuck in stars '*', he will go to the last point where he had at least two selections to go to.
That point were saved at:
void ifo(int x,int y){

```
if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x-1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y-1][x]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
if(arr[y+1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
if(arr[y][x-1]==' ' && arr[y-1][x]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
if(arr[y][x-1]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
if(arr[y-1][x]==' ' && arr[y][x+1]==' ') {a=y;b=x;}
}
```

and the backwards moving happens at this part:

```
while(1){

if(y==a && x==b){ l++; break;}
if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
if(arr[y][x+1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }
if(arr[y-1][x]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; y--; }
if(arr[y][x+1]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; x++; }
if(arr[y+1][x]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; y++; }
if(arr[y][x-1]=='o') { arr[y][x]=' '; x--; }


}
```

after he arrived, at the spot 'a' and 'b', he adds one on 'L', so the modulo of L gets !=0. that means he will now go the other path, he wouldnt have went last time.
In every stack of Code it asks if the next step into the left or into the right equals an 'A' (german for Ausgang, english for Exit), if that happens, it shall printf the whole Array, and exit.

```
void ausgabe(){

    for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){


    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){


    printf("%c ", arr[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    exit(0);

 }
```

I hope i could explain it a little understandable. Sorry for my bad english knowledge.

Comment: Check if `arr[y][x-1]`, arr[y-1][x]`, etc. is in the array before accessing them.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get it

Comment: if you call ifo with numbers like ifo (50,50) you will exceed the array boundary.

Comment: but I dont see, the cases where it could get to such big values. what could be a possible solution for that?

Comment: The point is that near the boundaries in the rest of your program you might call it with 0 or something.  We don't see the rest of your program.

Comment: what, i posted 100 lines of code there. how much do u guys see?

Comment: I will update my answer I see the problem.

Comment: `if(arr[y][x-1]=='A') { void ausgabe(); }` does nothing: `void ausgabe();` is just a function declaration.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Off-topic here, we won't debug your homework!

Comment: OH MY GOSH, IT WORKS !!!!!!!!!! I LOVE YOU GUYS, such astupid mistake ive spend hours with

Answer (score 3):

Use a debugger. If you're using GDB, you can stop at the SEGV using:

`(gdb) handle SIGSEGV stop`

`(gdb) r` - runs the program

`(gdb) backtrace`